# Is there any way can we train Document Intelligent(form recognizer) custom model using already labelled samples?

Tags: python, azure, ocr, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to train an Azure document intelligent(custom model) using the **custom model** option,

labeling is a time-consuming long process, we can't label the sample again and again, I understand form recognizer requires only 5 samples to start with, what if I have mutliple edge case samples
so I have prelabelled data in **COCO format**, is there any way I can use this data for training the custom model?